# rendering doesn't work properly

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation, blender-internal-render-engine

when i do rendering my image quality goes very low than what should i do?? i am using blender 2.8. i am inserting a 3d model than i had done rotation on this 3d model. the texture of the 3d model not rendering and show blank[image: After Rendering]

[image: before Rendering]

Comment: Looks like you have intersecting geometry that may be hidden in the viewport, but not in the render. There's a leather watch strap that's not visible in the viewport. Additionally your lighting seems way to bright.

Comment: is that graphics driver error??

Comment: if i will install graphic driver this problem will be solve or not??

Comment: From what I can see this is just a misconfiguration of your lighting and you've likely hidden some objects in the viewport (eye icon in the outliner) without disabling it in the render as well (camera icon in the outliner). Try to find the brown wrist strap object in your hierarchy.

Comment: yes i was find brown strip and remove from it .than after what should i do?

Comment: thank you for your answer. problem solved.